# C: Usar funcion free() para liberar puntero doble de caracteres correctamente

Tags: c

Tengo una función en la cual necesito implementar el uso de free() para liberar la memoria que fue utilizada. Mi código lo tengo escrito de esta forma:

```
void totalDePaisesVisitados(ALUMNO* array, int nu_Alumnos){
  int ArrayLenght = 0;
  int MaxPises = 70;
  int lastIndex = 0;
  char** stringAr = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)*MaxPises);
  for (int i = 0; i < MaxPises; i++) {
    stringAr[i] =  (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
  }
  for (int a = 0; a < nu_Alumnos; a++) {
    int numberPaises = array[a].pais->n_pais;
    //printf("%s %d\n","numero de paises", numberPaises);
    for (int b = 0; b < numberPaises; b++) {
      int enArreglo = 0;
      for (int c = 0; c < ArrayLenght+1; c++) {
        //printf("%s %s %s %s\n","Comparando: ",array[a].pais->nombre[b],"con: ",stringAr[c]);
        if (strcmp(array[a].pais->nombre[b],stringAr[c]) == 0) {
            enArreglo = 1;
            //printf("%s\n","Encontrado en el arreglo" );
        }
      }
      if (enArreglo == 0) {
          //printf("%s\n","ENCONTRADO PAIS DISTINTO" );
          stringAr[lastIndex] = array[a].pais->nombre[b];
          ArrayLenght++;
          lastIndex++;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("%s\n","#3");
  printf("%s %d\n","Numero de Paises visitados:",lastIndex);
  for (int i = 0; i < MaxPises; i++) {
    free(stringAr[i]);
  }
  free(stringAr);
}
```

El problema con esto es que si libero la memoria, aparece un error:

> malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe4356005d0: pointer being freed was
>   not allocated

¿Cúal es la manera correcta de liberar la memoria en esta función?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en esta parte de código:

```html
      if (enArreglo == 0) {
          //printf("%s\n","ENCONTRADO PAIS DISTINTO" );
          stringAr[lastIndex] = array[a].pais->nombre[b];
          ArrayLenght++;
          lastIndex++;
      }
```

Específicamente cuando asignas stringAr[lastIndex] porque en ese momento pierdes la referencia que recibiste con la llamada a malloc.

Te recomiendo usar la función strcpy para copiar la cadena sin perder la referencia.